# pingbacks testing

Tags: cron, testing, pingbacks

I have a few questions regarding functionality testing of PBs in a new wp installation (3.0.4):

1. Are pingbacks sent immediately when a post is published, or are they scheduled as a cron job? If the later is correct, how often does the job run and can I trigger it manually?
2. Are there any other terms for PBs to be sent besides having "Attempt to notify any blogs linked to from the article" set to on, and of course a link to another blog in the post content? (for example, should the sender post be public and not private? should the blog be non private?)
3. Should the outbound link be placed in the post content or can it be placed in a custom field of the post in order for the PB to be sent?
4. In case PBs are not sent nor received in my blog, what is the best way to debug and detect the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Q: Are pingbacks sent immediately when a post is published, or are they scheduled as a cron job? If the later is correct, how often does the job run and can I trigger it manually?**

A: You can install [core control (wordpress plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/) to find out more.

**Q: Are there any other terms for PBs to be sent besides having "Attempt to notify any blogs linked to from the article" set to on, and of course a link to another blog in the post content? (for example, should the sender post be public and not private? should the blog be non private?)**

A: Wordpress can and does not care about external resources being somewhat public or private as  somewhat undefined terms.

**Q: Should the outbound link be placed in the post content or can it be placed in a custom field of the post in order for the PB to be sent?**

It need to be placed into the content.

**Q: In case PBs are not sent nor received in my blog, what is the best way to debug and detect the problem?**

Log and analyze the in- and outbound network traffic of your site with a focus on HTTP requests to find out more what is going at all and probably going wrong. Additionally, the core control plugin I linked above can be helpful for cron related debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer hakre, however, when I installed core control on two of my blogs I didn't see any task related to pingbacks. Here's what I see:
wp_version_check, wp_update_plugins, wp_update_themes, wp_scheduled_delete

Comment: In addition, I didn't see how that plugin can help me with the debugging

Comment: @user1567: http://tinyurl.com/6d6enao

Comment: I have read the discussion in core.trac thoroughly and tried various suggestions including: publishing a post that links to another author's post in my plog (self ping), adding add_action('admin_footer', 'cron_debug');

function cron_debug() { var_dump(get_option('cron')); } to see the cron array and it does not include anything about pinging, and also Karen's solution http://blazingminds.co.uk/wordpress-stops-pinging-fix/ . Unfortunately non of it works for me.